# ColorMatrix for partial gray scale

Tags: c#, gdi+

So I'm using a variation of something I found on the web to convert images to gray scale. I'd like to be able to "fade to gray" I.e. fade the color incrementally so I can go from full colour through partially coloured to pure gray.

```
public static ColorMatrix ColorMatrixForGrayScale = new ColorMatrix(new[] {
                             new[] {.3f, .3f, .3f, 0, 0},
                             new[] {.59f, .59f, .59f, 0, 0},
                             new[] {.11f, .11f, .11f, 0, 0},
                             new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                             new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1} });

    public static Bitmap MakeGrayscale(Image original, int percent = 100)
    {
        ColorMatrix matrix = GetMatrix(percent); // returns a variation of the above.

        //create a blank bitmap the same size as original
        var newBitmap = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height);

        //get a graphics object from the new image
        var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap);

        //create some image attributes
        var attributes = new ImageAttributes();

        //set the color matrix attribute
        attributes.SetColorMatrix(matrix);

        //draw the original image on the new image
        //using the grayscale color matrix
        g.DrawImage(original, new Rectangle(0, 0, original.Width, original.Height),
           0, 0, original.Width, original.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);

        //dispose the Graphics object
        g.Dispose();
        return newBitmap;
    }
```

So the question is two parts. First, can I use a matrix for that? If yes, what do I vary, if no, what is a workable approach? I'm thinking of creating full gray scale and then merging it with the colour image (some how).

Thanks

edit: Original source [Switch on the code](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale)

Comment: What do you mean by partial gray scale? On area being colored and the rest gray scale (that's called colorkey)? Not sure what you mean

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make that clear. Imagine a picture that is just all red. Convert it to gray scale and it would be all gray. Partially convert it and the colour would be somewhere between red and gray.

Comment: I think like reducing the saturation while keeping light and hue the same?

Comment: For saturation look at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/78995/Image-colour-manipulation-with-ColorMatrix

Comment: Perfect, pop it in an answer and I'll vote for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the saturation there is an interesting article at http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/78995/Image-colour-manipulation-with-ColorMatrix